# Getting parent route parameters in Angular 2 (router v3.0.0-alpha.6)

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, angular2-template

Looking to set up a site using one of [Google's recommended practices for multi-regional and multilingual websites](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en), particularly the model of utilizing subdirectories with gTLD's (ex. www.stackoverflow.com/en/questions/ask, www.stackoverflow.com/fr/questions/ask, etc).

Depending on the top-level subdirectory I'd like to set default language and fetch the appropriate JSON data. To futher explain, when a user navigates directly to [www.mywebsite.com/en/home](http://www.mywebsite.com/en/home) the default language will be set to `en` and my content service will fetch the `en.json` file.

In the example above my routes would be configured like so:

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: ':country',          component: Home },
  { path: ':country/home',     component: Home },
  { path: ':country/about',    component: About },
  { path: ':country/contact',  component: Contact }
];
```

I'm trying to figure out how to grab the `:country` route parameter (if URL is [www.mywebsite.com/en/about/](http://www.mywebsite.com/en/about) I'm trying to get the `:country` route parameter value of `en`) when in the `Home`, `About`, or `Contact` component. Here's a couple of things I've tried:

```
export class Home implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) {}

    private sub: any;

    ngOnInit(){
       this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
         let country = params['country'];
         console.log(country) // undefined :(
       });
    }
}
```

I've also tried using `route.snapshot` like so:

```
export class Home implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(){
        let country = this.route.snapshot.params['country'];
        console.log(country) // undefined :(
    }
}
```

Also have tried working with this solution to no avail: [Angular 2 access parent routeparams from child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34906888/angular-2-access-parent-routeparams-from-child-component)

If anyone has an idea of another approach please share!

Comment: You've mentioned 'parent route parameters' in your question title. Are these the only routes that you have defined in your app or are they children in another `RouterConfig`

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure why this didn't work for you, but I just tried and the following code works for me:

```
import {Component, OnInit}              from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute }       from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  template: '<h1>Home: {{country}}</h1>'
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  country: string;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) {

    this.country = '?';

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       let country = params['country'];
       this.country = country;
       console.log(country);
     });
  }


}
```

When I navigate to the root page, it displays `Home:`, the `/en` page displays `Home: en` and the `/fr` page - `Home:fr`. It works similarly for the "about" page.

The full source is [here](https://github.com/serebrov/so-questions/tree/master/angular2-router).
Update: [here is also live demo (plunker)](http://plnkr.co/edit/ymlXIXGnuRdAVwMZsGVU?p=preview).

Resources:

- [Angular guide - Routing & Navigation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)
- [Routing plunker example](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/router/ts/plnkr.html)
- [Angular Router post by Victor Savkin](http://victorsavkin.com/post/145672529346/angular-router)

Comment: I have the same issue but in Angular 2 Final version. Pls help